# Cannot bypass Omniauth initializer in test mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, graphql, omniauth

I am trying to test my graphql schema without any need for authentication.

I have added `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to the `GraphqlController`, and when using postman (copied by a curl request from graphiql), and I am seeing a successful query in development mode.

In postman I have the query in the body `{"query":"{\n  user(id: 1) {\n    id\n    created_at\n    updated_at\n    jwt\n}\n}\n","variables":null,"operationName":null}`, and Content-Type application/json in the header and this works fine.

Now in test mode, I am hitting the auth initializer for Omniauth:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(
    :auth0,
    Auth0::Config["app_client_id"],
    Auth0::Config["app_client_secret"],
    Auth0::Config["domain"],
    callback_path: "/auth/auth0/callback"
  )
end
```

Although I don't want to since I don't want any headers required in this post request.

Here is my rspec request:

```
require 'graphlient'

RSpec.shared_context "GraphQL Client", shared_context: :metadata do
  let(:client) do
    Graphlient::Client.new('https://api.example.org/graphql') do |client|
      client.http do |h|
        h.connection do |c|
          c.use Faraday::Adapter::Rack, app
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and here's the actual test

```
it 'retrieves schema' do
  expect(client.schema).to be_a GraphQL::Schema
end
```

with the error:

```
 Failure/Error:
   expect { client.schema.status }
     .to raise_error(Graphlient::Errors::ServerError)

   expected Graphlient::Errors::ServerError, got #<ArgumentError: Received wrong number of arguments. [nil, nil, nil, {:callback_path=>"/auth/auth0/callback"}]> with backtrace:
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/omniauth-auth0-1.4.2/lib/omniauth/strategies/auth0.rb:41:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! I forgot to add keys for test in config/auth0.yml.

It was a hidden file.